# Wix Patches: Autogenerate GUI not working. Any alternate way?

Tags: wix, patch

I'm working with Wix Patches based on [pcp method](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/patch_building.htm). In my case, I may have to generate multiple patches, with multiple products.

If we generate patches with same GUID, only 1st would be installed and so we have to change GUID every time.

Now * method doesn't work in patches:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <PatchCreation
      Id="*"
      CleanWorkingFolder="yes"
      OutputPath="PID_x64_100_103_Patch_.pcp"
      WholeFilesOnly="yes"
       AllowMajorVersionMismatches="no"
       AllowProductCodeMismatches="no"        
  >
```

I'm now looking for some alternate method to auto-generate GUID. Is there any command line util (freeware of course)..

Thanks

Comment: May i know did you solve the problem? I am running into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

As patches are designed to upgrade just the differences from one version to a another i.e. 1.2 to 1.3 having the patch id set to "*" is completely invalid. Unless you have a script to generate the pcp file comparing the latest build to the previous one (or another previous version), you shouldn't be automatically generating the Id, you should pre-generate and manually create the PCP file.

If you need to generate a Guid either use an online [guid generator](http://www.guidgen.com/) or if you have visual studio installed you can use TOOLS>Create Guid which uses the [GuidGen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw069h38.aspx)

Comment: Caveman, when we have to create multiple patches for one build to be installed side by side, you need to change the GUID or it will not install.

I've started using UUIDGen.exe coming with Windows SDK (7.0 in my case) and it generates GUID at command line which GUIDGen.exe can't give at command line.